# Searching for quotation marks in a varchar(max) field

Tags: sql, quotation-marks, varcharmax

I have a field in a table set to VARCHAR(MAX) and I am unable to search for quotation marks ["].
If I search for any other character it is working.

```
select * from xml_file_log where request like '%"%'
```

Comment: It works for me with MS SQL 2008R2 where the value in the table is `asasas"asas`

Comment: Is it a double quote `"` or single quote `'`. Because I just tested your query and for double quote it works just fine. And what database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: After further review it looks like the " is actually not a char(34) character.  Now off to see if I can track down what it actually is.

Comment: I was an escaped character that SQL 2008 management studio was converting.  As a result it failed if you searched for ", but &quot; is what it needed.  Here is the query that worked. select * from xml_file_log where request like '%&quot;%'